# How to delete unwanted programs in fatdog64 800 to release space?

Tags: puppy-linux

How can one delete programs from [fatdog64](https://distro.ibiblio.org/fatdog/web/) [800](http://lightofdawn.org/blog/?viewDetailed=00197) to release space? I just installed Firefox version 66, which takes a lot of space and memory, and there are some programs I know are heavier, such as GIMP.

This live session CD starts at > 950 MB of space in the [save file](https://distro.ibiblio.org/fatdog/web/faqs/no-savefile.html); right now it is 550 MB. I don't know how to delete the program folders.

Comment: You may wish to consider use of Falkon http://falkon.org instead of Firefox; Falkon is significantly lighter.

Comment: well it can be firefox, blender,etc, any other program, but i want to know if i can use a program from the pendrive instead of install ing it in the savefile

Comment: That's a different question than what was originally posed. Please click [edit] and rephrase it, which will attract more eyeballs and get you an answer more quickly.